# Including interaction on a graph

Tags: usability, interaction-design, design-patterns, ios

I'm doing some design work for a client on an iOS app and I've got a question about adding interactivity to a graph.  It's a wine app and the idea is a user answers some questions and the app creates a profile of the types of wine the person might like based on their answers.  The client has asked to add in some info about each of the styles.  I've added it as a kind of accordian menu.  I'm worried that it doesn't really look clickable (I have added a hint underneath to help) or is it even appropriate to do something like this.  The other concern I have is I've used vertical accordians elsewhere but they're styled differently so now I have the same pattern with two different visuals.

Before tap:
[image: before tap]
After tap:
[image: Afer tap]

Answer (score 1):

*Everything* looks click-able on a mobile device :-P

What I don't understand, is your desire to drag the user into every corer of your app.

As I see it, the graphs will give the (novice) user sufficient information.  I'm pretty sure that more advanced users would tap the label or the graph if they wanted to read more about the details.  But I'm not sure, so this is one of the simple tasks you should throw at random people in the hallway.  Give them the phone and just ask them them what "Aromatic" means and where they would look for more information about that.

If this information is an essential part of the app (and not something you want to leave for "exploration"), then you could add a simple icon behind each bar to increase the affordance of these elements:
[image]

Comment: "But I'm not sure, so this is one of the simple tasks you should throw at random people in the hallway. Give them the phone and just ask them them what "Aromatic" means and where they would look for more." +1 nicely said

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody.  I showed my client and he liked the idea of the hint.  What I'm thinking is once the user taps the profile once, the hint can be hidden automatically as the behaviour should have been learnt.  The audience is a bit older for this app so I want to make is super clear what they can do.  Plus this is an update so we're adding new interactivity to an existing page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that hints are the worse possible solution. It's like putting "Pull" on a door handle. You have several solutions. I would recommend having the phrase "clickable graphs" or "after having clicked the graph" interspersed in the copy;  or instead of titleing the graph "XXX Graph" call it the "XXX [Clickable |Interactive | appropriate wod] Graph"